# Roundcube sends logout when List completed

Tags: roundcube

I have set up roundcube v1.3.7 on a new LEMP-server (ubuntu/18.04.2, nginx/1.14.0, mariadb/15.1, php/7.2.7). I use it to connect to a dovecot/2.2.22 server.
When logging in, I do see the inbox and the other folders but no contents. I can still logon from an older roundcube client on a different LAMP server...

The debug logging on the new roundcube client

```
tail /var/log/syslog
Sep 13 17:00:04 new7 roundcube: <ev9jh27h> [454B] S: * LIST (\Subscribed) "." Verzonden
Sep 13 17:00:04 new7 roundcube: <ev9jh27h> [454B] S: * LIST (\Subscribed) "." Archief
Sep 13 17:00:04 new7 roundcube: <ev9jh27h> [454B] S: * LIST (\Subscribed) "." Junk
Sep 13 17:00:04 new7 roundcube: <ev9jh27h> [454B] S: A0003 OK List completed (0.000 + 0.000 secs).
Sep 13 17:00:04 new7 roundcube: <ev9jh27h> [454B] C: A0004 LOGOUT
Sep 13 17:00:04 new7 roundcube: <ev9jh27h> [454B] S: * BYE Logging out
Sep 13 17:00:04 new7 roundcube: <ev9jh27h> [454B] S: A0004 OK Logout completed.
```

The debug log on the older roundcube client

```
tail /var/log/roundcube/imap
[13-Sep-2018 17:02:52 +0200]: <pqkajgt1> [B5D4] S: * LIST (\Subscribed) "." Verzonden
[13-Sep-2018 17:02:52 +0200]: <pqkajgt1> [B5D4] S: * LIST (\Subscribed) "." Archief
[13-Sep-2018 17:02:52 +0200]: <pqkajgt1> [B5D4] S: * LIST (\Subscribed) "." Junk
[13-Sep-2018 17:02:52 +0200]: <pqkajgt1> [B5D4] S: A0003 OK List completed (0.000 + 0.000 secs).
[13-Sep-2018 17:02:52 +0200]: <pqkajgt1> [B5D4] C: A0004 STATUS INBOX (MESSAGES UNSEEN)
[13-Sep-2018 17:02:52 +0200]: <pqkajgt1> [B5D4] S: * STATUS INBOX (MESSAGES 1634 UNSEEN 74)
[13-Sep-2018 17:02:52 +0200]: <pqkajgt1> [B5D4] S: A0004 OK Status completed (0.000 + 0.000 secs).
[13-Sep-2018 17:02:52 +0200]: <pqkajgt1> [B5D4] C: A0005 STATUS INBOX.Bewaar (MESSAGES UNSEEN)
[13-Sep-2018 17:02:52 +0200]: <pqkajgt1> [B5D4] S: * STATUS INBOX.Bewaar (MESSAGES 29 UNSEEN 1)
```

In the the developers console of my chromium browser I see 6 errors

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://MY_SITE/program/js/jquery.min.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.      common.min.js?s=1532894748:48
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined    at common.min.js?s=1532894748:48     app.min.js?s=1532894748:36
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined    at new rcube_webmail (app.min.js?s=1532894748:36)   at ?_task=mail&_token=myfEJNj0Yg5rtzoO2Qmwmgx8i9awI5da&_token=Pjg7HzBC8z8srant4yqSMY8T2UgoSwwK:45   jquery-ui.min.js?s=1532894746:6 
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined    at jquery-ui.min.js?s=1532894746:6    at jquery-ui.min.js?s=1532894746:6
```

I did remove cookies from my browser, used different browsers, disabled all roundcube plugins...

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

The "js" error messages in the browser console made me double check the installation. It appears there were some javascrip dependencies that had to be installed, as documented on [roundcube.net](https://roundcube.net/news/2017/04/25/release-candidate-for-version-1.3)

These two lines solved my problem

```
# cd /usr/share/nginx/roundcubemail/
# bin/install-jsdeps.sh
```